# How to sort index of a Series when index is months

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my Series

```
Date
April        389
August       406
December     350
February     361
January      333
July         389
June         400
March        383
May          417
November     372
October      383
September    406
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```

I want to sort this so the index becomes January, Fenruary, March....
I tried this code:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_index()
```

I got this output:

```
Date
NaT    389
NaT    406
NaT    350
NaT    361
NaT    333
NaT    389
NaT    400
NaT    383
NaT    417
NaT    372
NaT    383
NaT    406
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```

How can I fix it?